# Confused between GLM,LME and GLMM. What should i use for my non normal data of animal behaviour?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

So I have a dataset of behavior of a certain animal (n =  36 individuals) and the observations were taken for 4 months. The data has lots of zeroes in it and is right skewed and I wanted to measure the effects of a certain set of variables on the response variable (the behavior). But I am unable to point out which model I should go for LME, GLM or GLMM

What I have tried using? I tried using lme and I was getting the desired results but then I read that it is for normally distributed data

Comment: What is your outcome/target variable?

Comment: @Will my target variable is the rate of behavior and the predictor variable is microclimate variable like temp,hum, wind speed

Comment: Poisson GLMM then maybe?